# Need samples of big endian encoded tifs

Tags: image-processing

Folks I've written a small utility that extracts some (and only some) header information from Tifs.

To test it fully I need some Big Endian Tifs, but I cant find any, and I can't find anything to generate them.

Does anyone know of a public repository for tifs with big endian encoding? Or of something that can generate some?

Thanks, apologies if this is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

The current ImageMagick can make them.  Given a little-endian TIFF,

```
convert le.tiff -endian msb -define tiff:endian=msb be.tiff
```

and *vice versa*:

```
convert be.tiff -endian lsb -define tiff:endian=lsb le.tiff
```

Run

```
identify -verbose be.tiff | grep ndian
```

to see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Every TIFF begins with a two-byte flag indicating its endianness. If you can get your hands on a database of TIFF files, you can write a simple script to read the first two bytes and filter out the ones that match your desired endianness. I doubt that such a specialized database would exist somewhere on the web.

Comment: Thanks, I've run it on every tif I can find here in house but unfortunately none of them are BigEndian. The idea is to test that it works before running it in the field on an image repository with millions of images, many of which may be BigEndian, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can always convert little endian images to big endian images yourself by changing the order of bytes. Again, a pretty simple script should do that. This way you can create such database artificially yourself.